# Mostrar ou Ocultar modal com sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

estava pesquisando uma forma de limitar o aparecimento de um modal em meu site, por exemplo ao clicar em um link pede o cadastramento do e-mail antes de ir para a ancora, mas não quero que isto apareça sempre, e sim uma vez por sessão!
Achei algo sobre o session storage, consigo fazer por ele isso? Não entendo muito de javascript, desculpe minha ignorância!

Obrigada pessoal.

Codigo do meu modal.

```
  <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Meu site.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Deseja receber mais informações por e-mail?</p>
      <form name="email" action="enviaEmail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="enterEmail" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        </div>
              <!--Oculto para mandar o produto clicado-->
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="cliqueSistema" id="cliqueSistema">    

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Alerta1()">Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Consegue sim. Você gravaria na sessão que a modal já foi exibida. E toda vez que a página for carregada você verifica na sessão se é para abrir a modal ou não.

Se o site estiver no ar ou tiver um trecho de código que monta sua modal. Coloca para auxiliarmos.

Comment: Coloquei o código que estou usando do Modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É como o Rodrigo respondeu. Como você está utilizando Bootstrap segue um exemplo para complementar. É interessante verificar se o navegador suporta Storage para não atrapalhar o restante do seu script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var exibirModal = true;

    // Verifica se o navegador possui suporte a Storage.
    // E verifica na variável de sessão se a modal já foi aberta.
    if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined' && sessionStorage.getItem('modalExibida') == 'true') {
      exibirModal = false;
    } else {
      exibirModal = true;
    }

    if (exibirModal) {
      $('#myModal3').modal('show');

      if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
        sessionStorage.setItem('modalExibida', 'true');
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Obrigada pessoal! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Quando ele fechar o modal use:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('ja_exibiu', 'true');
```

Depois para validar se é a primeira vez ou não, use:

```
if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('ja_exitiu') == 'true') {...}
```

Lembrando que, o sessionStorage não guarda o tipo de dado, é tudo string